How to draw 3D figure where y and z changes with x in LaTeX?
If there are three conditions,

x belongs to [0,5]
y belongs to [2x,7x]
z belongs to [0,x+3y]

Is there a way to draw this 3D figure?
It should be like this

This code is not right
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={60}{30}, % Adjusts the 3D view angle
            xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
            fill opacity=0.6, % Transparency for surfaces
        ]
        \addplot3[surf,domain=0:5,y domain=2*x:7*x] {0,x+3y};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{3D region}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Note that TikZ and the like are not primarily made for plotting 3D graphs. I am unsure how the result should look like, could you provide an image?

@JasperHabicht Thanks for your feedback. I have added a fiure.

On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks. I have added the code which is wrong. I don't what is the right code.

As others wrote, Tikz doesn't provide such perspective transformations. At least you have 2 options: 1) act like an artist and redraw THIS specific 2D projection of a 3D situation, 2) create a bitmap, or better a pdf, with an other tool AND include it via the graphicx package.

@MS-SPO Sad story. I once thought that it may not be difficult.

@Y.zeng it is not a question of difficulty, but of choosing a suitable tool. it is difficult to mix a cake with a toothpick. tikz can use gnuplot for plotting functions and gnuplot can render 3d. (I don't know about exactly what it can do in terms of perspective etc., but it is more powerful and, as I understand it, not inherently 2d, though I might be mistaken about that.) https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main/ci/master/tree/. see the pgf/tikz manual for details of how to incorporate the tool into your picture. or use asymptote or, even I believe, metapost.

there is also tikz-3dplot but I do not recommend using it for anything complex. it helps you to fake 3d in 2d by doing some of the calculations, but the process is still awkward and it is not bug-free. it is fine for simple things, but I don't think it would be a great idea for this unless you are absolutely determined on a tikz solution.

@cfr When there are too many vertices, it is easier to use other drawing tools. When there are few vertices, draw all the faces and fill them with colors. This is the more feasible method I can think of at present.

@Y.zeng it's not so much the number of vertices as the involvement of perspective and viewing angle. but it is also true that more complex calculations are best done outside tex and, especially, not in pgfmath.

Hi! I guess that your volume is characterized by 5 points (in space).  It is a pyramid with basis a trapezoid.  I'll call the points O, for the origin, A, B, C and D.  A and B are in the plane z=0, and given in coordinates by (5, 10, 0) and (5, 35, 0).   All four points lie on the plane x=5.  Now C=(5, 35, 5+215) and D=(5, 10, 5+65).  You can use tikz-3d --- having the points you just draw a trapezoid and four triangles.  For the colours, there is another story, but we can touch it later. Now the numbers are large, especially for C; maybe you can change in the formula 3y into 1/2y.

Just compute the vertices and draw the solid using plain TikZ. I think the key here is choosing the scale for each axis because the dimensions are very different.
You can do something like this:
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{% STYLES
   axis/.style={thick,-latex},
   aux/.style={dashed,draw=gray,text=black},
   solid/.style={thick,draw=blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,
                    x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(-0.07cm,0.1cm)},z={(0cm,0.05cm)}]
%  COORDINATES
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (5,10,0);
\coordinate (B) at (5,35,0);
\coordinate (C) at (5,35,110);
\coordinate (D) at (5,10,35);
%  AXES
\draw[axis] (O) -- (6,0,0)   node[right] {$x$};
\draw[axis] (O) -- (0,40,0)  node[left]  {$y$};
\draw[axis] (O) -- (0,0,125) node[above] {$z$};
%  DASHED LINES AND NUMBERS
\draw[aux] (0,10,0) node[left] {$10$} -- (A) -- (5,0,0) node[below] {$5$} -- (5,0,35) -- (D);
\draw[aux] (B) -- (0,35,0) node[left] {$35$} -- (0,35,110) -- (C);
\draw[aux] (0,35,110) -- (0,0,110) node[left] {$110$};
%  SOLID
\foreach\i in {O,A,C}
  \draw[solid=0] (B) -- (\i);
\draw[solid=0.7] (O) -- (A) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw[solid=0.5] (O) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
%  MORE DASHED LINES AND NUMBERS
\draw[aux] (5,0,35)  -- (0,0,35) node[left] {$35$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

and get this output:

